# Convert a Pandas Series from Timedelta to Microseconds

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timestamp, timedelta

I have a Pandas `Timedelta` column that may be created like this:

```
import pandas as pd
tdelta_ser = pd.date_range(start='00:00:00', periods=3, freq='700ms') - pd.date_range(start='00:00:00', periods=3, freq='500ms') 
tdiff_df = pd.DataFrame(tdelta_ser, columns=['TimeDiff'])
print(tdiff_df)

                TimeDiff
0        0 days 00:00:00
1 0 days 00:00:00.200000
2 0 days 00:00:00.400000
```

Looking for a really concise **one liner** that will produce a new column with this time delta converted to microseconds, without making assumptions about the internal dtype of the pandas Timedelta column being in int64 nanoseconds.

**Desired result**

```
               TimeDiff  DiffUsec
0        0 days 00:00:00         0
1 0 days 00:00:00.200000    200000
2 0 days 00:00:00.400000    400000
```

I tried several methods. The most concise was the one below, but it makes assumptions about the internal working of the Timedetla column being int64 nsecs and requires a scaling factor of 1000 to get it right.

```
tdiff_df['DiffUsec'] = tdiff_df['TimeDiff'].astype('int64') / 1000
print(tdiff_df)

                TimeDiff  DiffUsec
0        0 days 00:00:00       0.0
1 0 days 00:00:00.200000  200000.0
2 0 days 00:00:00.400000  400000.0
```

Comment: "it makes assumptions about the internal working of the Timedetla column being int64 nsecs" - good point. Note that you can check the unit with `tdiff_df['TimeDiff'].dt.unit`. I'd still use `tdiff_df['TimeDiff'].astype(int).floordiv(1000)`, or adjust the scaling factor according to the unit.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the `total_seconds()` method, which will return the total duration in seconds for each `Timedelta`. Multiplying the result by 1,000,000 since there are 1,000,000 microseconds in a second and this will give you the desired microseconds value. This should handle fractions of milliseconds as you pointed out.

```
import pandas as pd

tdelta_ser = pd.date_range(start='00:00:00', periods=3, freq='700ms') - pd.date_range(start='00:00:00', periods=3, freq='500ms') 
tdiff_df = pd.DataFrame(tdelta_ser, columns=['TimeDiff'])

tdiff_df['DiffUsec'] = (tdiff_df['TimeDiff'].dt.total_seconds() * 1e6).astype('int64')
print(tdiff_df)
```

which results in

```
                TimeDiff  DiffUsec
0        0 days 00:00:00         0
1 0 days 00:00:00.200000    200000
2 0 days 00:00:00.400000    400000
```

Comment: Nice approach. A one liner with no assumptions about pandas time scaling factor internals.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've initialized your data with 'ms' you can get that as a new column:

```
tdiff_df['TimeDiff'].dt.components.milliseconds
```

Output:

```
0      0
1    200
2    400
Name: milliseconds, dtype: int64
```

But if you're timedelta has a different initialization, nanosecond or microsecond, you can get those by the `dt.components` attribute:

```
print(tdiff_df['TimeDiff'].dt.components)
```

Output:

```
  days  hours  minutes  seconds  milliseconds  microseconds  nanoseconds
0     0      0        0        0             0             0            0
1     0      0        0        0           200             0            0
2     0      0        0        0           400             0            0
```

Comment: Nice answer @Suraj.  The `dt.components` Idea is very useful, the milliseconds are easily converted to microseconds without making assumptions about int64 internals in pandas.  But if there were any fractions of milliseconds in the column it would not convert correctly to microseconds. For example 200.3 milliseconds would produce 200 milliseconds my this method, and converting it to microseocnds would yield 200000 which is incorrect.

Comment: Ooh then something like `dt.components.milliseconds + dt.components.microseconds * 1e3 ... `  might be a solution, But it gets lengthy

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch more tries here's a hidden gem that was buried in Pandas docs.

```
tdiff_df['DiffUsec'] = tdiff_df['TimeDiff'].dt.microseconds
print(tdiff_df)
                TimeDiff  DiffUsec
0        0 days 00:00:00         0
1 0 days 00:00:00.200000    200000
2 0 days 00:00:00.400000    400000
```

Comment: this is just the microsecond *component*, not the full timedelta as microseconds.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @FObersteiner.  I re-checked it with 1.4 seconds deltatime and it produced an incorrect result .```                                                TimeDiff  DiffUsec
0        0 days 00:00:00         0
1 0 days 00:00:00.700000    700000
2 0 days 00:00:01.400000    400000```